# Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, вопросы-по-метке

Что должно быть включено в хороший вопрос касающийся структурированного языка запросов (SQL).

Перевод: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

**Каноническая ссылка:** `[Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035)`

Comment: перевод ответа добавлю позже, много текста. здесь будет аналог FAQ из англоязычной meta?

Comment: Как мне видится: если написать FAQ, то FAQ будет. Тут модераторский тег [meta-tag:faq] имеется — видимо, неспроста.

Comment: Вы можете также занести это в [информацию по метке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Думаю, ссылки может быть достаточно. Главное, чтобы она была заметна.

Comment: Было бы хорошо галочку поставить.

Comment: Изменил каноническую ссылку, чтобы она перемещала сразу на ответ.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Выясните, что необходимо для ответа на вопрос. Вопрос должен быть кратким и по теме.

Задайте себе вопрос: если я ничего не знаю про систему, настройки и окружение, как проще всего их описать?

Не тратьте время на избыточный текст или код, если эта информация не относится напрямую к вопросу. Вопрос должен быть кратким, конкретным, детальным и включать соответвующий пример кода. Если нам потребуется больше информации, мы сообщим об этом в комментариях.

## Написание хорошего вопроса. Структура вопроса.

Представьте следующую аналогию: когда вы пишете вопрос, вы пишете эссе. Есть несколько ключевых моментов, которые нам необходимо знать перед тем как мы сможем вам помочь.

### 1. Формулировка: с какой проблемой вы столкнулись?

> | плохо | хорошо |
> | --- | --- |
> | "Выдаёт ошибку" | "Выдаёт следующую ошибку (полный текст сообщения об ошибке)" |
> | "Не работает" | "Не работает фрагмент запроса (пример запроса)" |
> | "Что случилось" | "Как мне сделать (описание желаемого результата)" |

В плохих примерах не сформулирована задача. Они не дают сообществу информации о том, в чём может быть ошибка.
В хороших примерах вы говорите сообществу, что вы натолкнулись на ошибку или не можете осознать следующий шаг в своём запросе.

Нам сложно разобраться в вопросах, которые не содержат этих деталей. Мы не можем понять, что вам нужно, если вы сами не уточните это. Более подробные и детальные формулировки проблем привлекают более качественные ответы.

### 2. Предоставьте контекст: какие данные вы использовали, что вы уже попробовали, какие попытки предприняли?

#### 2.1. Во–первых, вам стоит предоставить пример данных, чтобы сообщество могло увидеть, с чем вы работаете.

Данных должно быть немного, но достаточно, чтобы показать с чем вы работаете. Обычно 5-15 строк достаточно для читателей вопроса, чтобы получить представление о данных.

Пример:

> таблица : people
>
> | id | name | status | phone |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | John | 1 | 214-444-1234 |
> | 2 | Mary | 0 | 555-111-1234 |
> | 3 | Jeff | 0 | 214-222-1234 |
> | 4 | Bill | 1 | 817-333-1234 |
> | 5 | Bob | 1 | 214-555-1234 |
> | 6 | Martin | 1 | 314-555-1234 |

#### 2.2. После того, как вы показали, на что похожи ваши данные, вам следует показать, что вы уже попробовали сделать.

> Я написал запрос в таком виде, но не знаю как быть дальше
>
> ```sql
> SELECT id, name, status, phone
> FROM people
> WHERE status = 1;
> ```
>
> Мне нужно отфильтровать не только поля по условию `status=1` но так же с номером телефона, начинающемся на `214`.

Это сообщает нам не только чего вы хотите добиться, но и что вы уже попробовали. Таким образом вы получите ответ гораздо быстрее.

#### 2.3. Задумайтесь об использовании SQL Fiddle

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/), [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), [SQLize](https://sqlize.online/) и прочие online fiddle просты в использовании: укажите свои DDL / DML запросы (create, insert, update, alter и т. д.) и свой запрос (select, set и т. д.), убедитесь, что все запросы выполняются так, как должны, и дайте ссылку на созданный fiddle. Не забудьте проверить в предварительном просмотре, что ссылка открывает именно созданный fiddle.

Когда вы предоставляете пример в SQL Fiddle, вы позволяете людям самим проверить запросы, как Ваши, так и создаваемые для ответа. Вы не только получите ответ быстрее, но он ещё и будет протестирован.

Не забывайте предоставлять информацию о структуре и данных в самом запросе. Пример в SQL Fiddle улучшает вопрос, но не является достаточным сам по себе.

### 3. Покажите какой результат вы ожидаете получить

Это необходимая часть вопроса, которую часто забывают указать. Вам нужно показать что вы хотите сделать с данными на случай если кто-нибудь не поймёт ваш вопрос или формулировку проблемы. Таким образом они увидят как вы хотите манипулировать своими данными и могут сделать это для вас.

Пример:

> Я хочу получить результат запроса в таком виде:
>
> | id | name | status | phone |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | John | 1 | 214-444-1234 |
> | 5 | Bob | 1 | 214-555-1234 |

### 4. Проверьте набор входных данных

Предоставленные входные и ожидаемые данные должны помогать ответить правильно. Если приведённый неработающий код на предоставленных данных отрабатывает верно, то надо дополнить их таким образом, чтобы ожидаемые и фактические результаты отличались.

Очевидно так же, что ожидаемый результат почти всегда должен быть непустым.

### 5. Дополнительные предложения

Также, чтобы улучшить свой вопрос, вы можете добавить DDL / DML запросы, относящиеся к вашему запросу.

Вы можете включить их в сам вопрос или создать [сниппет](https://gist.github.com/), если данных слишком много:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people(
  id int,
  name varchar(55),
  status int,
  phone varchar(55)
);

INSERT INTO people VALUES
(1, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'),
(2, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'),
(3, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'),
(4, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'),
(5, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234');
```

Если вы пытаетесь добиться наилучшей производительности или хотите получить совет по настройке индексирования, то обязательно добавьте в вопрос:

1. План выполнения запроса (`EXPLAIN`) для своих таблиц. `EXPLAIN (query) \g` может быть предпочтительнее, так как он выводит результаты построчно, таким образом их легче прочитать:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT id, name, status, phone
FROM people
WHERE status = 1;
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|   ID  |   SELECT_TYPE |   TABLE   |   TYPE    |   POSSIBLE_KEYS   |   KEY     |   KEY_LEN     |   REF     |   ROWS    |       EXTRA   |
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|   1   |   SIMPLE      |   people  |   ALL     |   (null)          |   (null)  |   (null)      | (null)    |   5       |   Using where |
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

2. Полные `CREATE TABLE` для всех использованных в запросе таблиц (выполните `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` и выложите результат). Так можно сразу увидеть, какие в таблицах имеются индексы, ограничения и т.п. Не выкладывайте результат выполнения `DESCRIBE` - там информации гораздо меньше. Также добавьте `CREATE`-коды представлений и пользовательских функций, если таковые используются.

## Форматируйте свой вопрос — сделайте его приятным для глаз!

- [Как оформить код в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)
- Для форматирования SQL кода можно использовать инструменты типа http://sqlformat.org/
- Для форматирования таблиц можно воспользоваться [конструктором таблиц](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

## Обязательно примите ответ, решивший вашу проблему

Когда кто-то ответил на ваш вопрос, обязательно [ПРИМИТЕ ОТВЕТ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), решивший вашу проблему. Печально наблюдать невостребованные хорошие ответы.

Не забывайте голосовать за полезные ответы и против бесполезных.

---

Перевод: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/1004997)

Comment: Я вашу инструкцию теперь рекомендую почти в каждом вопросе по SQL: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444985/181472

Comment: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html - не работает ссылка

Comment: @AnastasiaVovremya поменял на свежую ссылку из англоязычного вопроса

Comment: Тоже регулярно даю ссылку на тему. Но есть предложение. Поскольку абсолютной точности перевода не требуется (да вообще достаточно "по мотивам"), разумно будет немного перетасовать пункты, чтобы не было прыжков в логике. Например, пункт 5 должен явно идти перед пунктом 2.3, а пункт 2.2 - наоборот, после него.