# Краткое описание метки - диссонанс между правилами и "практикой"

Tags: обсуждение, описание-метки, отклонённые-правки

Не подумайте, что жалуюсь :)

Более опытные товарищи отклонили предложенные описания меток с таким обоснованием:

> Если просто написать, что означает [метка], это вряд ли принесет пользу, если только название метки не двусмысленно само по себе. Краткое описание должно объяснять, почему и когда стоит применять данную метку. Узнать больше можно в Справочном центре.

Чтение соответсвующей статьи в Справочном центре просветления не принесло. Полистал "Мету" - результат тот же. Пошел привычным путем: посмотреть что написано в других метках. Результат несколько озадачивает:

1. Есть метки, где краткое описание под вышеупомянутый критерий не подпадает никак, например php, html, css, c++ и таких много и не только на ruSO:

> PHP — популярный скриптовый язык программирования общего назначения, активно применяемый для разработки веб-приложений.
>
> HTML — Стандартный язык разметки гипертекста, повсеместно применяемый в интернете. Последняя действующая версия спецификации HTML5. Как правило используется совместно с шаблонизатором, серверными и клиентскими скриптами, каскадными таблицами стилей для динамической генерации удобочитаемых веб страниц из информации хранящейся в БД сервера.
>
> CSS — формальный язык описания внешнего вида документа, язык стилей, определяющий отображение HTML-документов.
>
> С++ — язык программирования общего назначения, синтаксис которого основан на языке С.

2. Фраза подобная "Используйте эту метку для вопросов, относящихся к языку Java или инструментам из платформы Java" появляется в нескольких метках и на мой взгляд притянута за уши к Правилу, согласно которому в описании метки должно быть указано когда её применять. Складывается впечатление, что можно для любой метки, например **штуковина**, дописывать предложение "Используйте эту метку для вопросов, относящихся к штуковине" и метка станет образцово-показательной.

Настолько-ли нужна такая норма что в метке *обязательно* должны присутствовать указания почему и когда её следует применять?

Comment: Хотел вам написать, но вы опередили с этим вопросом. Отвечу обязательно, чуть позже только. Вопрос про описания меток я когда-то поднимал, но большой активности в нем не было, и мой собственный ответ я уже считаю устаревшим. Однако, там есть некоторые полезные ссылки: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527/181472

Comment: Быстро составил описание для метки [tag:HTML] и еще десятка других меток на нулевой странице в первый день когда подняли эту штуковину. Руководствовался здравым смыслом и интуицией. Не понимаю зачем кому-то вообще может потребоваться пояснение в каких конкретно ситуациях стоит использовать метку [tag:HTML]. Может мне еще надо пояснить как задавать вопросы чтобы они не вызывали ненависть и отвращение окружающих?

Comment: @igumnov: вот про вопросы можно бы на каждой странице писать, но не поможет. :)

Comment: @igumnov: Остроумно, но не по делу. Даже в простых, казалось бы, случаях как HTML, иные [умудряются метить данной темой вопросы по favicon](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/275711/revisions), например.

Поройтесь на мета-сайтах StackExchange в разделах /questions/tagged/tags — уверяю, найдёте немало пищи для размышлений.

Answer (score 4):

Попробую объяснить свою позицию.

Очередь проверок устроена достаточно негибко. Единственный вариант, в котором я могу оставить автору сообщение, озаглавлен «Несёт вред». Но ваши правки определенно не были вредоносными. Наоборот, очень хорошо, что вы решили организовать информацию по инструментам, с которыми вы работаете. Мне бы хотелось, чтобы там была кнопка «Отлично, что вы этим занялись, но надо бы еще добавить вот что:...». Вряд ли такую добавят.

На мой взгяд, предложенные краткие описания не целиком решали свою задачу: давать краткую инструкцию по использованию метки и, возможно, задаванию вопросов.

Если я нажму «Принять», это будет означать, что я полностью одобряю текст, а вы можете больше над ним не работать. Но я считаю (субъективно), что этого недостаточно, и что вы можете сделать гораздо лучше.

[Что было](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24249):

> Assetic - фреймворк с открытым кодом для PHP 5.3. Позволяет создавать и использовать различные инструменты для упорядочения статических ресурсов (скриптов, стилей и изображений) для разрабатываемых веб-приложений

Что я бы, пожалуй, сам написал (не факт, что это принял бы отдельно взятый специалист по assetic или опытный участник SO ).

> Assetic - фреймворк для упорядочения статических ресурсов веб-приложений на PHP 5.3. В вопросе обязательно используйте метку [php], укажите используемую версию assetic. Чтобы задать хороший вопрос, используйте инструкцию в полном описании метки.

Подразумевается, что в полном описании инструкция есть, хотя бы краткая. Вот примеры хороших инструкций: [регулярные выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/info), [SQL](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/181472). Не факт, что автор вопроса прочтет краткое описание метки и пойдет читать инструкцию. Но я уверен, что для каждой большой темы такая инструкция нужна, чтобы можно было явным образом дать на нее ссылку. Инструкцию логично размещать в полном описании метки (если входит), или на Мете (если она очень подробная).

Возможно, вместо указания на инструкцию где-то еще следует дать инструкции прямо на месте:

> Assetic - фреймворк для упорядочения статических ресурсов веб-приложений на PHP 5.3. В вопросе обязательно используйте метку [php], укажите используемую версию assetic, опубликуйте достаточный для воспроизведения проблемы код и полные сообщения об ошибках.

Как спрашивал в комментариях @igumnov:

> Может мне еще надо пояснить как задавать вопросы чтобы они не вызывали ненависть и отвращение окружающих?

Да, я за то, чтобы пояснять. Это выглядит немного избыточно, конечно. Но в чем у нас точно нет переизбытка, так это в хорошо заданных вопросах. А <s>зима</s> сентябрь близко...

Что касается других кратких описаний меток: на мой взгяд, определения в них часто избыточны, а инструкции — недостаточны. Если я захочу узнать, как используется HTML, очень маловероятно, что я открою SO и пойду читать краткое описание метки. Аналогично, это не то место, где стоит писать, является ли каждый отдельно взятый язык:

- динамическим, статическим, строго/нестрого типизированным, функциональным, объектно- и компонентно-ориентированным, императивным, декларативным, устаревшим, современным, свободным, проприетарным;
- поддерживающим лямбды и замыкания, указатели, приведение типов, вывод типов, обобщенное программирование, управление памятью, управление потоками, контрактное программирование;
- подходящим и неподходящим для веба, десктопа, мобильных приложений, игр, серверов, встроенных (embedded) устройств, дронов и луноходов.

Меньше всего в кратком описании метки я жду увидеть "hello world" (см. [jquery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)).

Однако, всё это встречается. Должен заметить, что у нас ситуция, пожалуй, лучше чем на EN.SO, где процветает копипаста из Википедии. И есть все шансы сделать ещё лучше.

Comment: Хм. Здравый подход. Причем тут как-то гораздо понятнее чем в других вопросах и ответах на "мете". Меня только смущает второй пункт из моего вопроса и его фактическое продолжение в данном ответе: "Чтобы задать хороший вопрос, используйте инструкцию в полном описании метки". Мне, как участнику сайта, будет весьма странно видеть такое предложение в кратком описании метки, а если оно будет во всех кратких описаниях - это будет явный перебор.

Comment: Кроме того, мне кажется, что метка выполняет два назначения: 1) структурирование информации с целью улучшения поиска информации по заданной теме; 2) дополнительный контент для внешних поисковых "пауков". Со стороны обоих пунктов вышеупомянутое предложение - просто вода. Остается воздействие на качество задаваемых вопросов и тут у меня возникают сомнения, что метками можно исправить ситуацию. Многие пользователи явно не даже читают правила перед написанием вопроса, а уж описания меток и подавно.

Comment: @tutankhamun: про инструкции — смотрите правку в ответе. Про поисковую оптимизацию ничего не могу сказать, не разбираюсь.

Comment: Вот хорошо вы это все пишете (кстати про Assetic неплохое краткое описание, можете публиковать :), но есть одно сомнение. Я ни разу не задавал вопросы на сайте, только на "мете", но по меткам собирал информацию и при наведении на метку смотрел о чем это вообще. Наверное поэтому мне кажется, что писать там инструкции о том, как ей пользоваться - избыточны. Потому что думаю так: "Если писать вопрос, то метки - это как ключевые слова. О чем вопрос, то и должно быть в метках". При этом что там в их описании - совершенно не задумывался бы.

Comment: @tutankhamun: метки, в общем-то, и есть ключевые слова. Для читателей в метке полезно название и первое предложение с определением. Я сам метки чаще всего использую для поиска, да и подписан на пару штук.

Answer (score 4):

Что говорят правила (доступны прямо на той же странице где мы редактируем описание метки) о выдержке из описания (*excerpt*):

> The usage guidance, or tag wiki *excerpt*, is a short blurb that
>   describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.

то есть выдержка должна содержать *когда* и *почему* данная метка должна быть использована на сайте -- это *все* правила. Всё остальное посвящено редактированию *полных* описаний и там же приведена ссылка на [обсуждение "Важность качественного описания меток"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/188/23044).

Человек, задающий вопрос, видит выдержки при выборе меток для вопроса. Задача краткого описания, чтобы не была использована неподходящая метка и подсказка какие ещё метки могут быть использованы, например, вот выдержка из описания [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python):

> Python — высокоуровневый язык с динамической типизацией,
>   ориентированный на создание читабельного кода. Одновременно
>   востребованы две параллельно развивающиеся версии языка Python — 2 и
>   3. Пожалуйста, используйте дополнительную метку [python-2.7] или [python-3.x], если ваш вопрос ориентирован на конкретную версию.

Описание говорит, что на этом сайте следует использовать слово python, а не питон, пайтон итд, чтобы обозначить вопросы, относящиеся к соответствующему языку программирования. И указывает, что возможно полезно добавить [python-2.7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) или [python-3.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) метки по необходимости.

Это формат "X это Y" (первый вариант). Правил он не нарушает потому что ясно, когда и почему данную метку использовать (в вопросах, относящихся к языку Python).

Назначение первого предложения в описании -- уникально определить слово в *пределах сайта*, но так чтобы оно было ясно людям, которые слабо со сайтом знакомы (большинство спрашивающих на большом SO). Задача не научить, а напомнить.

Если Ваши правки были в таком формате, то формат *сам по себе* ещё не является причиной для отказа.

Вторая форма: *"X это Y. Используйте X метку для вопросов об Y*."* может быть полезна, если она используется в *полном* описании. Как программист, Вы должны понимать, что даже если Y и Y* выглядят похоже -- это ещё не значит, что Y* не несёт новой информации. К тому же в полном описании допустимо выразить одну и ту же мысль несколько раз, но разными словами -- для разных людей разные описания оптимальными являются (кто-то больше примеры понимает, кто-то из первых принципов любит учиться). Вторая форма более явная. Не стоит DRY принципом злоупотреблять.

**Кратко**: правила и практика согласуются в аспектах, указанных в вопросе.

Comment: Даже не [tag:python-2.7], а [tag:python-2.x], т.к. бывают вопросы по более ранним версиям. Поправил [краткое](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24633) и [полное](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24632) описания.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: должно использоваться именно `python-2.7` по умолчанию и только если человек использует более ранную версию тогда её надо приводить.