# Если просто написать, что означает [метка], это вряд ли принесёт пользу

Tags: обсуждение, описание-метки

Достаточно большое время я провожу в очередях проверки, в том числе и очереди проверки описаний меток.

При обсуждении кратких описаний меток есть типовая причина отклонения:

> Если просто написать, что означает [метка], это вряд ли принесёт
>   пользу, если только название метки не двусмысленно само по себе.
>   Краткое описание должно объяснять, **почему** и **когда** стоит
>   применять данную метку. Узнать больше можно в [Справочном
>   центре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts).

И я лично (возможно и другие проверяющие) не понимаю, в каких случаях использовать данную причину, а когда нет.

Я не наблюдаю системы в применении метки.

Случайный проверяющий, который только получил доступ к этой очереди, скорее всего ткнёт "принять" на любое краткое описание метки, более-менее прилично составленное. И возможно, даже не догадается, что нужно в кратком описании должно содержать фрагмент по применению данной метки.

Тем не менее, я не понимаю систему, по которой часто модерирующие эту очередь то применяют эту причину, то не используют.

Давайте попробуем выработать общий подход, а для этого поясним, когда и как правильно использовать эту причину.

В качестве "затравки" для обсуждения привожу несколько примеров из очереди проверок:

- [disqus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/242749)
- [assembly](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/242097)
- [svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/241991)
- [tensorflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/241772)
- [fontawesome](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/241678)
- [nlp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/241035)
- [anaconda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/239028)
- [svg-animation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/238940)
- [asp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/238491)

Comment: Ну, основной источник по описаниям меток, это статья Джефа (https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/) Там объяснено довольно четко, в каких случаях нужно не определение понятия, а указание на особенности применения для конкретного сайта.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1096/Краткое-описание-метки-диссонанс-между-правилами-и-практикой?rq=1

Comment: Про fontawesome - мне было лень переводить полное описание с enSO )

Answer (score 4):

> Тем не менее, я не понимаю систему, по которой часто модерирующие эту
>   очередь то применяют эту причину, то не используют.

Потому что человек не может разбираться во всех технологиях, про многие из которых он, вероятно, даже никогда не слышал.

Ну вот возьмём [assembly](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly). У нас эта метка про .NET-приложения, хотя на en SO, к примеру, эта [метка](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info), в первую очередь про Ассемблер.

Если человек никогда не работал с C#, то про .NET assembly он бы и не знал и для него метка бы не была неоднозначной. Если бы такой человек писал описание такой метки, то, вероятно, просто про ассемблер и написал.

**UPD:** чтоб итог подвести.

1. Да, такое надо только для неоднозначных меток. Но, кто определит их неоднозначность?
2. Незнание - лишь одна из причин. Наряду с этим я вижу ещё проблему связанную с тем, что людям, которые очередь проверяют, в целом безразлично качество ресурса.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то вы считаете, что фрагмент "как применять метку" обязателен только для неоднозначных меток. И проблемы в применении вызваны тем, что не всегда известно, где ещё такой же термин использутся.

Comment: Да, только для неоднозначных. Проблемы в применении вызваны различными факторами, я лишь привёл одну из возможных причин.

Answer (score 3):

Как написано в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)

> Часть меток являются общим знанием. Большинству меток требуется краткое обозначение, даже если это всего 3-4 слова. Но если метка является общим знанием — то есть, если вы подойдете к случайному прохожему на улице и скажете ему имя метки, он будет знать о чём идет речь, и о чём вы говорите — в этом случае можно обойтись совсем без обозначения. В кратком описании метки укажите только то, чем является метка для сообщества.

Соответственно, данная причина отклонения применяется только к правкам, предлагающим определение понятия, которое всем очевидно. Для них краткое описание вместо этого должно содержать сведения об особенностях использования метки на сайте. Например, нетрудно понять, что описание

> Google - это поисковая система

к метке [google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) будет абсолютно бесполезно. Правку, предлагающую его, нужно отклонить.

Если метка обозначает специальный технический термин, краткое описание может содержать только определение. Например, для метки [mmdevice](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mmdevice):

> MMDevice API - интерфейс для получения информации об аудиоустройствах в Windows

не надо отклонять. (Это не значит, что краткое описание таких меток должно содержать *только* определение, оно может дополнительно содержать и рекомендации по использованию.)

---

Ну и конечно, некоторым меткам нужно не описание, а синонимизация к более популярной метке или вообще сожжение. Описания в стиле "капитан очевидность" для явно бессмысленных меток нужно несомненно отклонять.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю что краткое описание самой технологии необходимо в кратком описании метки, так как это очень удобно, если технологию не знаешь, просто наводишь мышку и сразу понятно о чём речь.

Конечно как использовать метку это нужно писать в определённых ситуациях, но я считаю что само название метки должно говорить как её надо использовать.  Если там какие-то заумные и нетривиальные правила, то это рождает путаницу.

Желательно что бы было так: Видя метку мы сразу понимаем о чём речь.

Это сродни правилу хорошего интерфейса, что без каких-либо мануалов интуитивно понятно что и как сделать. Либо в программировании что название функции сразу должно давать понимание о её использовании.

И только в каких-то исключительных ситуациях нужны разъяснительные правила по использованию метки.

---

[nlp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/241035).

Есть двойственность понимания, так как кроме Natural-language processing (NLP) - "Обработка естественного языка", есть ещё и другая технология Нейро Лингвистическое Программирование, которое имеет то же сокращение. Так что в кратком описании метки надо указать о чём идёт речь. Но тут думаю достаточно просто написать это в кратком описании, и нет необходимости писать что использовать метку в такой ситуации... Так как эта информация уже будет ясна из расшифровки самого сокращения.

Comment: Насчёт "и только в каких-то исключительных ситуациях" - как раз и стоит вопрос, когда эти ситуации наступают. Вы определение исключительных случаев не дали, в справке их нет (но неявно подразумевается, что в каждом кратком (в полном даже нет такой причины отклонения) описании метки должен быть пример использования). Также я не вижу никакой последовательности в правоприменительной практике: каждый в очередях на своё усмотрение трактует эту самую "исключительность".

Answer (score 0):

Не нравится мне это буквоедство. То есть по факту получается, что человек постарался, сделал пусть даже одно или несколько осмысленных предложений, объяснив суть понятия, и этот труд давайте отвергать, потому что "можно было бы и получше". Неужели лучше никак? Пусть лучше метка висит вообще без описания?

Я с этим не согласен. Это никак не мотивирует делать описания меток. Поэтому большинство меток без описания. И я после таких баталий на мете и некоторых проверяющих, которые рубят старания, считая что они делать благородное дело, очень не факт, что когда-либо возьмусь за этот неблагодарный труд.

---

Может всё-таки если  лучше с описанием метки, чем без него, то просто будем принимать его? И пусть каждый как может вносит свою лепту в описания? Неужели +2 в репутацию это прям такой джекпот, который заслуживает тяжёлых испытаний? Мне кажется такими стараниями желающих добавлять описания будет всё меньше и меньше.