# Добавление кратких описаний меток должно соответствовать критериям

Tags: обсуждение, описание-метки

Хочу обратить внимание тех, кто занимается созданием кратких описаний меток.

Ваше стремление положительно, но хочу отметить, что краткое описание метки должно соответствовать критериям, которые описаны здесь: [Что должно содержать краткое описание метки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts).

Заглядываю в очереди проверок и попадаются добавления кратких описаний меток, которые не содержат один важный пункт, вот этот:

> Напишите общее правило использования этой метки. Другими словами, какие вопросы должны сопровождаться этой меткой? Метки предназначены только для организации вопросов, поэтому без правил использования метки в определённых вопросах, эти вопросы совсем не будут сопровождаться метками, что делает описание метки чисто теоретическим. Думайте об этом, как о рекламе: в комнате, полной меток, которые кричат «выбери меня!», что сможет убедить задающего вопрос выбрать именно вашу метку?

Выбор меток при создании вопроса - одно из важных действий. По метке можно искать, фильтровать, игнорировать. Но часто наблюдается путаница, поэтому важно добавить в крактое описание **в каком случае должна использоваться данная метка** и/или **когда не должна**.

Пример из последнего:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В любом случае, наличие описания лучше, чем ничего.

Comment: В данном примере вообще [tag:efcore] надо синонимизировать в [tag:entity-framework-core].

Comment: Заметил ещё и другое не очень подходящее поведение, когда в полное описание метки предлагается ровно тот же самый текст, что и в кратком описании. И такие правки ревьюверы одобряют, к сожалению.

Comment: @Nofate ты ж модератор :) Надо - синонимизируй!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ сам модератор ) Но я больше о том, как стоило поступить автору описания метки с 1 вопросом и проверяющим.

Comment: @Nofate я пробовал как то синомим создать. Не очень популярная фича, ждал оборения год... если не больше. Нет желания этим заниматься, к сожалению

Comment: @Dmitry Надо на мете пост просто делать. Синонимов создано куча уже. А вот список предложенных синонимов запрятан далеко и нет никаких уведомлений от него.

Comment: @Dmitry с данной правкой еще одна проблема: этот текст один в один скопирован со стороннего сайта (легко находится поисковиком, вот источник: https://habr.com/ru/articles/694086/), это тоже нужно проверять и отклонять. Конкретно этот участник постоянно так делает.

Comment: @insolor то да, я на другое внимание обращаю. Очень часто попадается указанный мной пробел в кратком описании. Здесь первый попавшийся пример

Comment: По синонимам меток есть [FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304152/339911) на MSE. Наверное, есть и другие, не удивлюсь. Но предлагаю плюсануть этот. Хотя, обычно это не влияет никак на планы компании взять что-то в работу. But who knows.

Comment: @Dmitry, я бы сказал, это типичный пример, который я постоянно вижу у этого участника, фактически в каждой его правке описаний меток: скопированное содержимое + отсутствует инструкция по использованию метки. Считайте, что это моя персональная боль (боль - потому что голосую за "отклонить", другие голосуют за принятие, в итоге очень часто такие правки принимают).

Comment: @insolor приму к сведению вашу боль =) буду внимательнее к правкам данного пользователя. Я принял данное описание, поленился проверить

Comment: @insolor демократия она такая. Надо было в модераторы баллотироваться.

Comment: Если метка однозначна (язык программирования, библиотека) вполне нормально начинать краткое описание с определения понятия. Формально добавлять "Используйте метку для ..." нет особого смысла, только загромождает ограниченное пространство, выделенное под него. Вот если описание скопировано или машинный перевод с английского SO, тогда да, это надо выжигать с особой жестокостью.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight данный момент тоже отображен в инструкции по ссылке в вопросе. Вот оно _Избегайте общего описания концепции, лежащей в основе метки, за исключением случаев, когда она слишком узкоспециальная_. То есть определение для ЯП (или других общих концептов, там пример с электронной почтой) нет необходимости писать, а вот указать в каком случае надо использовать данную метку, хотелось бы видеть.

Comment: @DiMithras везде есть свои плюсы и минусы, в том числе и в должности модератора. Пока минусы для меня перевешивают.

Comment: @Dmitry Обсуждалось уже несколько раз, не хотелось бы повторяться (см. например https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6985/240512 ). Вкратце, не ориентируйтесь особо на справку, реальная практика отличается от того, что в ней написано.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight абсолютно то о чем я и утверждаю. То же самое и написано в справке. Только в ответе на вопрос приведен пример с меткой `Google`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Если просто написать, что означает \[метка\], это вряд ли принесёт пользу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6976/%d0%95%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83)

Comment: @Зонтик по каким причинам вы ставите дубликат? Здесь не обсуждается общий принцип проверок/закрытия. Ничего не понимаю

Comment: @Dmitry смысл вопроса такой же, ИМХО

Comment: @Зонтик железная логика. Смысл вопроса про c++ - это про c++. Шикарно. Нет вопросов больше

Comment: @Dmitry ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ но суть вопроса одна и та же. Поэтому мне кажется, что это дубль.

Answer (score 2):

В вопросе мало примеров, поэтому попробую дать лишь общий ответ:

Описательное, пускай и не совсем соответствующее критериям описание метки, лучше, чем никакого. Если вы знаете как надо улучшить (и у вас на это есть время) - пожалуйста сделайте это, а не просто отклоняйте.

Что такое метка [efcore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efcore) без описания было бы решительно непонятно без просмотра вопросов с ней.

---

> Метки предназначены **только для организации вопросов**, поэтому без правил использования метки **в определённых вопросах, эти вопросы совсем не будут сопровождаться метками**, что делает описание метки чисто теоретическим

Это какой-то кособокий перевод. Полагаю, что надо обращаться к либо к первоисточнику, либо выяснять текущие практики.