# Список переведенных вопросов и ответов

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow, перевод-содержимого

**Оглавление:**

1. [**Связанные вопросы и ответы на основном сайте**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1263/181472)
2. [**Связанные вопросы и ответы на Мете**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1264/181472)

По следам следующих обсуждений:

- [Стоит ли переводить вопросы и ответы с англоязычного SO?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/70/181472)
- [Связь между вопросами на разных языках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347/181472)
- [Создание связей между одинаковыми вопросами на разных языках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431/181472)

Насколько я понимаю, для того, чтобы подтвердить актуальность предлагаемого изменения, нужны примеры вопросов и ответов, переведённых или просто аналогичных. Предлагаю собирать такие вопросы в один список. Когда у нас наберется несколько сотен, это будет очень весомый аргумент для [feature-request] на Meta.SE.

Группировка по основной метке, группы сортируются лексикографически. Внутри группы вопросы сортируются лексикографически по названию вопроса на Ru.SO. Слева на Ru.SO, справа на En.SO. Обозначения:

- `→` Переведен c русского на английский
- `←` Переведен с английского на русский
- `=` Просто два аналогичных вопроса

Answer (score 2):

## Связанные вопросы и ответы на основном сайте

> **Не создавайте новых ответов, дополняйте этот.**

### [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)

- [Оператор += в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417466/181472) ← [Java += operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8710619/2790048)

### [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)

- [Подсветка ключевых слов в TextBlock или RichTextBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/421031/181472) = [Highlight text in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5685644/2790048)
- [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole) ← [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli_result), boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)
- [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82) ← [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
- [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4) ← [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
- [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java) ← [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
- [Обрезание экрана при повороте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501787) = [View doesnt resize on rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156694/view-doesnt-resize-on-rotation)

### [git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git)

- [Как скачать только папки и файлы без репозитория?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/324693/181472) = [Using git to get just the latest revision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1209999/2790048)

### [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

- [Правила использования подчеркивания "_" в именах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417782/177684) = [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/343443)
- [Где взять стандарт C++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417797/177684) = [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/343443)

### [r](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)

- [Выбор папки Shiny](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491633) = [Choose dir shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357127/choose-dir-shiny)
- [rpivotTable и nvd3 rcharts в одном приложении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494583) = [An error occurred rendering the PivotTable results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694588/an-error-occurred-rendering-the-pivottable-results)

### [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

- [nvd3 контроль в две строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499794)  = [nvd3 controls into 2 line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796948/nvd3-controls-into-2-line)

Answer (score 1):

## Связанные вопросы и ответы на Мете

- [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/181472) ← [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/2790048)
- [Первооткрыватели документации: предложение расширения Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1247/181472) ← [Warlords of Documentation: A Proposed Expansion of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/2790048)

Answer (score 0):

## Связанные вопросы и ответы на других сайтах.

### [железо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be)

- [Экран в зеленых тонах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500416/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85) ← [Monitor not displaying color red…](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55478/monitor-not-displaying-color-red-is-this-the-monitor-or-some-setup-im-missing/139302#139302) С [apple.se]! Переведен не тот ответ, который принят автором вопроса, а тот, что помог.