# Полный список ассоциаций

Tags: поддержка, предложение, ассоциация-вопросов, data-explorer

В контексте активности по ассоциациям, хотелось бы видеть страницу со списков всех ассоциций.

Был пост [Список переведенных вопросов и ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1262/15479), но его никто не поддерживает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пока что можно [таким запросом](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/979992) список получить:

```
SELECT P.Id AS [Post Link], 
       C.text
FROM Comments C
INNER JOIN Posts P
ON P.Id = C.PostId
WHERE P.PostTypeId = 1 AND C.text LIKE N'%ассоциация:%'
```

Comment: You can do `concat('site://','questions/', P.Id, '|', P.Title)`  or `concat('site://','questions/', P.Id, '|', P.Id)` if you want a nice label for the link instead of that funky url. The first option basically mimics if you would do `P.Id as [Post Link]`

Comment: @rene thanks again (: