# Странные тревоги на мой вопрос

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

Я опубликовал вопрос: [Определение GPL лицензий используя RegEx(Регулярные выражения)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1418897/), через некоторые время пришла тревога о том что якобы **"Учебные задания допустимы только..."**(В самом низу вопроса вставлен полный текст тревоги). Там мне ответили на вопрос (я также отвечал на него), потом пришли ещё тревоги, снова об учебном задании, а третья тревога была о том что моя проблема больше не воспроизводится и так далее. Я вот чего не понимаю, вроде мой вопрос не подходит ни под одну из тревог, почему же на мой вопрос приходят тревоги? Надеюсь на подробное или не очень объяснение того почему же так много тревог, и низких оценок? (даже на ответ другого участника поставили плохую оценку, к слову почему-то *мой* ответ на *мой* же вопрос не трогали)

Заранее спасибо тем кто ответит!

<sub>Полный текст тревоги: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу**</sub>

Comment: Да кстати, у меня был вопрос-ответ, я сам ответил на свой вопрос, так что тревоги про учебные задания очень странные, ведь я уже приложил код решения (моего).

Comment: Причина про учебные задания - универсальная причина для закрытия вопросов, где автор не потрудился попытаться решить свою задачу/проблему.

Comment: @Эникейщик, но у меня ведь прямо в вопросе есть упоминание моего ответа, и, собственно говоря, сам мой ответ есть, с чего бы им ставить тревогу на мой вопрос?

Comment: Ну а как ещё использовать мусорную причину, кроме как для закрытия всего подряд?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вероятно, ваш вопрос минусуют и хотят закрыть по причине того, что он:

- Не содержит достаточного описания проблемы - у вас не указано, *ЧТО* вы собираетесь парсить. Большой текст, абзац, слова. А результат вам нужен 1, или набор. Нету примеров входных данных. Нету уточнения с чем именно у вас затруднения.
- В связи с этим, вопрос получился очень общий и не содержащий в себе конкретной проблемы как таковой. По сути его можно перефразировать в "Как мне регулярками найти похожие слова из списка?".
- Т.е. непонятно, в чем именно состоит вопрос, вы не можете написать регулярку, или не знаете как сделать перебор вариантов?
- Возникает впечатление, что вы не приложили усилий к формализации и описанию проблемы, а сразу решили запостить ответ который "сойдет".

---

Вопросы и ответы на StackOverflow предназначены в первую очередь для будущих читателей. Это база знаний (как Википедия). Поэтому важно их грамотно формулировать.

---

Я убрал всё лишнее из вашего вопроса:

1. *"Недавно у меня появилась задача, нужно было .."* - вступление не несущее смысловой нагрузки.
2. *"В интернете я не нашёл ответов .. (искал просто в интернете и в ruSO и SO)"* - бесполезное уточнение.
3. *"так что решил сделать сам (искал просто в интернете и в ruSO и SO), ниже вы можете увидеть как справился я(В ответах)"* - опять же лишнее бесполезное уточнение. Ответы располагаются в ответах. Да.
4. *"если у вас есть свои варианты, не стесняйтесь добавлять.?"* - опять же бесполезное уточнение.
5. *""Я не очень хорош в регулярных выражениях, так что могу ошибиться, если есть что добавить смело в комментарии к ответу (моему).* - и снова бесполезное уточнение.

P.S. В качестве доп.чтения, посмотрите ответ на вопрос - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1035/177188.

Comment: Спасибо, что указали на мои ошибки! В будущем попытаюсь избегать подобных вопросов или ответов!